# Redis::TimeoutError while using redis-rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, resque, redistogo

Updated to include Redis/Resque versions and stack trace (below):

```
redis (3.0.4)
redis-namespace (1.3.0)
  redis (~> 3.0.0)
redis-store (1.1.2)
  redis (>= 2.2.0)
resque (1.24.1)
  mono_logger (~> 1.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  redis-namespace (~> 1.2)
  sinatra (>= 0.9.2)
  vegas (~> 0.1.2)
resque-scheduler (2.0.1)
  redis (>= 2.0.1)
  resque (>= 1.20.0)
  rufus-scheduler
```

---

I'm seeing intermittent `Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out` on heroku while writing a moderately sized array (~200 Fixnums) to the Redis store using the `Rails.cache.fetch` command.

I'm also using Resque.

I see [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/redis/3.0.4/Redis/Client) that the Redis::Client can receive a timeout option, but I don't see where to pass initialization options to Redis.

I'm using the standard heroku `resque.rb`:

```
rails_root        = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env         = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

resque_config     = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
ENV['REDIS_URI']  = resque_config[rails_env]
Resque.redis      = resque_config[rails_env]
Resque.inline     = rails_env == 'test'

require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque/scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'

Resque.schedule   = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque-schedule.yml')

Resque.before_fork do
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

Resque.after_fork do
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

I assume that a Redis client is instantiated here.  Is this a different client from the one instantiated in `production.rb`:

```
rails_root          = ENV['RAILS_ROOT'] || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env           = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root + '/config/resque.yml')
config.cache_store = :redis_store, resque_config[rails_env], { expires_in: 14.days }
```

The options hash there is for `Rails.cache` options as far as I know.  Is a new client instantiated here?  How can I pass options to this one?

---

Updated to include this experiment in the heroku console implying that they are different client instances:

```
irb(main):002:0> Rails.cache
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisStore:0x00000003860e18 @data=#<Redis client v3.0.4 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:9485/0>, @options={:expires_in=>14 days}>
irb(main):003:0> Resque.redis.redis
=> #<Redis client v3.0.4 for redis://spinyfin.redistogo.com:9485/0>
irb(main):004:0> Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).object_id == Resque.redis.redis.object_id
=> false
```

---

Stack trace:

```
Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:208:in `rescue in io'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:206:in `io'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:214:in `read'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `block in call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:187:in `block (2 levels) in process'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:295:in `ensure_connected'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:177:in `block in process'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:256:in `logging'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:176:in `process'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:644:in `block in setex'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:643:in `setex'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-store-1.1.2/lib/redis/store/interface.rb:17:in `setex'
... 11 levels...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache.rb:299:in `fetch'
    ...SNIP...
    ...my code...
    ...SNIP...
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:6:in `each'
    ...SNIP...
    ...my code...
    ...SNIP...
    from (irb):5
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'irb(main):006:0>  !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       Operation timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    Backtrace:   /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:121:in `sysread'
                 /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/buffering.rb:121:in `readpartial'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:69:in `block in start'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:53:in `loop'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/client/rendezvous.rb:53:in `start'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:132:in `rendezvous_session'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:119:in `run_attached'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:24:in `index'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:206:in `run'
                 /Users/me/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
                 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku run rails c
    Plugins:     heroku-redis-cli
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.39.4 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: can you let us know which version of redis-store you're using? Configuration of timeouts is different for the newer gems. It would also be interesting to see a trace of where you're receiving the TimeoutError - specifically is it when connecting to Resque, or to the Redis connection you're using for your cache?

Comment: @BrianPO'Rourke Updated with several new pieces of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't much of an answer, but at the recommendation of a colleague, I switched from RedisToGo to openredis and these problems went away immediately.

Comment: This still happens for me on openredis

Answer (score 1):

The "Connection timed out" message means that `redis-rb` is having trouble initiating a connection to your Redis server. Normally, you'd want to just initialize your Redis connection once on app boot. However, because Resque forks (rather than using threads like Sidekiq), it has to initialize a fresh Redis connection for every individual job.

Normally, that's not a problem, but Heroku has intermittent issues with creating new Redis connections. I've seen this issue across languages / client libraries / Redis hosts, and beyond reducing the number of Redis connections you create, the only way to mitigate the issue is to automatically retry connecting to Redis a few times in your Resque.after_fork block. (Eg. catch the timeout error and either retry or re-raise the exception if you've tried 3 times)

Comment: This implies that Resque and redis_store share a client instance?  Check out my console experiment updated above.

Comment: To clarify, the error occurs when a `Rails.cache.fetch` attempt is made, not during a Resque job.

Answer (score -1):

You can't pass both a URL and an options hash to `config.cache_store`, because of [this bug](https://github.com/jodosha/redis-store/issues/37):

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, resque_config[rails_env], { expires_in: 14.days }
```

If you pass a URL and an options hash, it ignores the URL and defaults to localhost, which is probably why you're seeing a timeout (I just had the same issue).

Instead, do something like this:

```
redis_uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
config.cache_store = :redis_store, {
  host: redis_uri.host,
  port: redis_uri.port,
  password: redis_uri.password,
  namespace: "cache",
  expires_in: 7.days
}
```

Comment: I don't think so...  See the console output above which implies that the remote URL was being correctly set.